# One Symfony app with multiple domain

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony2 app, only on 1 server, but because it's internationalised, I have multiple domain names ( not subdomains ).
What I want to achieve is if a user change his language, I redirect to a different host and the user should be already logged in on the other locale.

I have 2 separate domain, like book.com and buch.de .
The initial problem, the user logs into book.com, where he changes his language to german so I want to redirect him to buch.de, but because of the other domain, the user will get a new cookie and he will not be logged in anymore.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `host` parameter in your route configuration:

```
homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     "example.{national_domain}"
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:Homepage }
```

Then you need to pass this `national_domain` parameter in every URL generation. I think that you can write some listener that will do it automatically.

To "share" cookies between domains you need one domain that will be main domain and do a Single Sign On. It will have all the needed cookies and you will be able to redirect user from this main domain to national domain with some GET parameters that will have all needed information.

One of the implementations of Single-Sign-On for Symfony you can find [here](https://github.com/treehouselabs/FMSingleSignOnBundle).

Comment: I have problem with the cookie, it has nothing to do with the routes.

Comment: Ok. This is another question. You need Single-Sign-On feature. You can use this bundle for that: https://github.com/treehouselabs/FMSingleSignOnBundle

Comment: Before I posted this question I spent like 3 hours with that bundle, but I couldn't get it work. If you have a working example I would glad to see it, because the documentation is very bad for that bundle ( they didn't even wrote that I need to update my DB) I don't even see, how would that implementation work.